# `PlotLegends` formatting mixing italics and upright letters

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, fonts

If I do:

```
ListPlot[Range[10]
,PlotLegends->Placed[LineLegend[{"Subscript[N, σ] f(m; μ, p)"},LabelStyle->{FontFamily->"Times"}],{0.8,0.35}]
]
```

where instead of the `Subscript` parts I've used the Insert -> Typesetting -> Subscript menu option from the front end, I get the following plot:

[image]

Why is the N italicized while the f, m, p are not? What can I do to make the N appear upright?

Comment: Look at [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics.html).

Comment: @LukasLang, interesting! I had noe idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you could create a `FormBox` wrapper before typing the legend, by using `Cell > Convert to.. > TraditionalForm`. A quick way to do this is to start typing a single letter, highlighting it and then invoking the conversion. From there on, you can continue typing the label and there won't be any visible difference until you evaluate the cell to create the plot. Then the `TraditionalForm` wrapper will insure that the default for single-letter symbols is italics.

Here is a movie showing how I typed this:

[image: typingInstructions]